# How to include a @XmlElement as inline element in jaxb?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I have a `spring-web` based `XML` service. It uses `JAXB` for mapping the bean to xml/json.

Question: how can I define one of the elements/classes to be included inline? Means: I don't want an extra node for it, but just plain include of the fields.

Example:

```
public class BeanDTO {
    private String name;
    private Address address;


    public static class Address {
        private String street;
        private String town;
    }
}


<beandto>
    <name />
    <street />
    <town />
</beandto>
```

Is that possible at all?

Comment: Xml Element is always a node as far as I can remember. I assume you want Xml Attribute. I would not advise that you go for including all fields of one class into an xml of other classes: too much strain on internal structure and keeping all fields and attributes unique.